# deferring dependencies when loading data using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

When my user logs in, I load a bunch of data from the server. This take a lot of time because it seems that the dependent observables are updated on every addition to an observableArray(). I would like to defer the evaluation of all dependencies until all data are loaded. I have seen how `deferEvaluation: true` can be used to affect the behavior of a specific `ko.computed()` variable, but I would like to isolate the observable until I know it's done being updated, and then invalidate the entire model to redraw the view.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/u3Np8/) to illustrate the problem. Note that in my real code, I am using the mapping plugin to load objects, but here I just simulate all the dependencies with a `.subscribe` function that gets called on every state change. I would like to prevent it from being called until the very end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, in a situation like this you would access the underlying array from an observableArray and push to it.  Then, you would either push the last one to the observableArray or call `myObservableArray.valueHasMutated()`.

So, in general it would look like:

```
var underlyingArray = this.items();
underlyingArray.push(one);
underlyingArray.push(two);
underlyingArray.push(three);
this.items.valueHasMutated();
```

In your fiddle, you could do `this.document().history().push(this);`.  Then, you would have to go back through and call valueHasMutated() on the the affected documents, if you wanted your subscription to run.

Comment: One issue with this solution is that it doesn't seem to work with the `ko.mapping` plugin. I am seeing updates propagate to the display from within the `ko.mapping.fromJS` call before the call completes.