# Deferring dependencies when loading data using knockoutjs, the scalar version

Tags: knockout.js

A while ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106236/deferring-dependencies-when-loading-data-using-knockoutjs) about how to defer updates to an `ko.observableArray` when doing batch updates, and the answer was to update the wrapped array and then trigger updates with a `valueHasMutated` call.

Is there an equivalent approach for deferring updates to a `ko.observable()`? I am finding a lot of time is spent updating and re-updating the dependencies when I update a bunch of data. Is there a good pattern for batching such updates?

Gene

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of thoughts in this area:

- there is a plugin that makes related updates more efficient: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates.  The author Michael Best is now involved with the KO project and has been helping us make some performance improvements.  This plugin may eventually get rolled into KO core in some form.  You should try this plugin and see how your app performs with it, as it will give us more evidence in the need for these type of changes.
- the other method would be similar to something that I wrote about a while back [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/pausing-notifications-in-knockoutjs.html).  Basically, your ko.computed properties have an extra dependency on an observable that you can toggle on and off.  When it is on, the ko.computed would do the actual evaluation (which would potentially create many dependencies).  When it is off, it would just return the most recent result and drop all of its dependencies other than the flag.  When you toggle it back on, then it would get re-evaluated again.  During heavy updates, you can pause until the updates are complete.

Comment: I was able to see an about 10x reduction in processing time by removing unnecessary sorts & other computations using the deferred update plugin, but some things are a bit unclear in the documentation. One problem I am having with it is figuring out how to apply `processImmediate` to `ko.computed` variables used by my bindings.

Comment: Feel free to post an issue/question on the plugin.  I know that Michael is definitely looking for feedback and would be happy to help you sort out your scenario.

Comment: Are there any tutorials available for this plugin? I'm super interested in this... I need to be able to pause a computed variable but also be able to write to it